Could not load Push topics even for Admin users
We are not able to get past this error in work bench even for Admins and we tried with different api versions and nothing helped.
Error: "Could not load Push Topics. Ensure the both the REST and Streaming APIs are enabled for this organization.
"

Any idea on how to get these working again?

Workbench is not supported by Salesforce and recommendation would be using EMP Connector for PushTopic events.
Here is the example for same.
